# Editing stripe monthly payments

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a working stripe subsection script but its grabbing the price from my stripe dashboard and i would like to set a custom price from a php variable ?

```
// The price ID passed from the front end.
//   $priceId = $_POST['priceId'];
$priceId = '123';


    

$stripe->products->create([
  'name' => 'Gold Special',
]);


$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/canceled.html',
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => 'price_1N85UGDJoBkKFUc1uui5YW02',
     
      
    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
]);



// Retrieve provider_session_id. Store in database.
//$checkoutSession->id;

// Send user to Stripe
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $session->url);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You typically get this error if have multiple account and you’re mixing them up and/ or you're mixing up your live mode/ test mode API keys. If you have multiple accounts, you’d want to confirm that this product is created on the [same account](https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys) that you’re making this call:

`$stripe-prices->all(['product' => '{{prod_NtsRaD5NAgvE4T}}', 'active' => true]);`

Next, you’d want to confirm that you’re using your [live mode/ test mode API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys) consistently. If you created the product in test mode for instance, you cannot use that product id in your live mode requests.

Comment: ive updated the post ive got the code to work but its now grabbing the price from the stripe dashboard and i would like to be able to set a custom price ( my users will be able to set a price )

Comment: Great, it looks like you're explicitly passing a Price Id on the Checkout Session creation request, 'price' => 'price_1N85UGDJoBkKFUc1uui5YW02'. If you're to let your customers choose the amount, you can follow this guide,https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pay-what-you-want.

Comment: im building a site like only fans i need my  users to be able to set the amount for the content there selling so user 1 can set $5 a  month to see there content  user 2 can set it to $6 a month i will store the price in a variable

Comment: I see, pay what you want is not supported for recurring prices. You might want to look at inline pricing, https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#inline-pricing in this case. These prices won't be reusable not you can update inline prices.

Comment: how do i get the CUSTOMER_ID ? can i set this to there insite username? Ive honestly been looking for around 2 weeks for this and im glad you said it can't be done though the way i was looking at. This seems very hard now i need to work out how to create a customer then grab there id

Comment: You'd want to look here, https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer. For subscription mode Sessions, Checkout will create a new Customer object based on information provided during the payment flow. Then, you can Retrieve the customer, https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve by that ID to use them later if you need to.

Comment: but this still requires the price from the dashboard